# Link godaddy domain with a site hosted elsewhere (

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy

I am a bigtime noob who is trying to figure out how to host his website!
So, I bought a domain name on godaddy and I want to use p4o.net as a web host.
but when I try use the nameservers of p4o.net in godaddy..its gives an error "nameservers not registered".
and now I have no idea how to fix this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your hosting provider for the correct nameservers to enter into GoDaddy.

Explanation:  A nameserver is what it says, a server for names. So GoDaddy needs you to enter the nameserver so it can lookup your domain name to find your site on p4o.net.

Your hosting provider tech support will need to add your domain name at GoDaddy into their nameserver and make it point to the IP address of your site on p4o.net. If you didn't already, then you need to get them to either show you how to make your site accept connections for that domain name or they might do that for you.

Then you enter the nameservers into GoDaddy.

After that it takes 24 to 48 hours for the new location of your domain name to "propagate" around to all the nameservers around the globe.

But the bottom line is that the tech support of your hosting provider can walk you through all of this step-by-step.

Sincerely,
Wayne

Comment: Thanks for ur help wayne! u explained it quite nicely.
and I was not sure how quick the tech support would respond since its a free web hosting provider..asking on a forum is always quicker :)

Comment: Sure. Understood. Since that's a free hosting service it's more likely that they setup this process as "self-service". If you have trouble getting help from them, then please post a new question here with the specific name of your host. Someone else might know exactly how to do it for your specific host, see? Otherwise, it's very different for each host.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your hosting site to get the correct nameservers or more info on why their nameservers might not be registered.